# How to tweak the radius scale of Sapling tree Gen add-on in blender v2.79?

Tags: sapling-addon

I'm following a Youtube tutorial on how to create a tree. The person in the tutorial is using Blender v2.75 while I'm using v2.79. He decreased the tree's radius scale to make it look more realistic, but I cannot find the same thing in my toolbar. I played with the custom shape settings but none of them seems to be right. Googled and found nothing helpful for this. Does anyone know where to find it in v2.79? Thank you!

[image]

Here's a link to the Youtube tutorial if that's helpful: https://youtu.be/gF6qkByl-_M?t=1037

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.79 has all 2.75 had and more. For this reason, some things got moved around/added and it can be more confusing. Allow me to help, then.

I think what you're looking for is this:
[image]

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you so much! I'm very new to Blender so yeah the interface is a bit confusing from time to time. The gif is very helpful <3